# The Glassfish server won't start after a restart

Tags: java, glassfish

In the beginning everything works fine, but after pressing the "restart" button the Glassfish server does not start. Exactly the same problem with the Payara server.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
INFORMATION: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
WARNUNG: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
WARNUNG: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@61f020ac in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\Users\Vladimir\GlassFish_Server\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\Users\Vladimir\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\Users\Vladimir\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\Users\Vladimir\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\logging.properties
  Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  5.1.0  (build default-private)|#]
  Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter|#]
  Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.|#]
  Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.|#]
  Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.|#]
  Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry|#]
  Authorization Service has successfully initialized.|#]
  Grizzly Framework 2.4.4 started in: 29ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]|#]
  JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]|#]
  Grizzly Framework 2.4.4 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]|#]
  Grizzly Framework 2.4.4 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]|#]
  Shutdown requested
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has a query component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:427)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:346)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:219)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:303)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:92)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:369)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:92)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
|#]
  Startup service failed to start
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has a query component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:427)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:346)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:219)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:303)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:92)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:369)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:92)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
|#]
  Grizzly Framework 2.4.4 started in: 84ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]|#]
  HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.10.Final|#]
  Server shutdown initiated|#]
  Shutdown required
MultiException stack 1 of 1
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has a query component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:427)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:346)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:219)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:303)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:92)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:369)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:92)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
|#]
  Server shutdown initiated|#]
  Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@6b3871d6 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@37095ded.|#]
  Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@6b3871d6 from service registry.|#]
  FileMonitoring shutdown|#]
Completed shutdown of Log manager service
  Shutdown procedure finished|#]
```

Because the site requires more details for the query, because I posted a lot of code. But I have nothing to add to the above. I'm just trying to get the server up and running and it's not working. Or rather it works, but after restarting it does not work anymore. Rebooting the computer does not help.

Comment: Please clarify how you get it to start again. Do you re-install glassfish? Do you start from asadmin after kill -9 or force shutdown of the process? Or did you only ever start it once successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I just killed the process that was using this server. I used the program "procexp64.exe" and selected the folder with the server files in it. The program showed me which process was using these files and I was able to kill the process this way.